# Youtube Iframe can't work without refresh

Tags: angular, youtube-iframe-api

To reproduce the problem in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mrzbpy), click `GO` to navigate to the component containing `iframe`, it works now, then go back and forward, the `iframe` disappears. You have to refresh the page to show the `iframe` again.

I tried some workaround :

- I tried to release the object in `ngOnDestroy` `window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = null;` but not success

This is the code how to create `iframe`

```
init() {
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.init();
  window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = (e) => {
            this.YT = window['YT'];

            this.player = new window['YT'].Player('player', {
              videoId: '1cH2cerUpMQ'
            });
  };
}
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
 <div id="player" >
 </div>
```

Someone has a workaround with success please share, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check if youtube api has been already initialized and then just create your player:

```
player: any;

init() {
  if (window['YT']) {
    this.createPlayer();
    return;
  }

  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = () => this.createPlayer();
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.init();
}

createPlayer() {
  this.player = new window['YT'].Player('player', {
    videoId: '1cH2cerUpMQ'
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = null;
  if (this.player) {
    this.player.destroy();
  }
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqdehh?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts)**

Comment: Wow, it works. Thanks for a simple solution. I'm newbie in angular

Comment: I will award you after 22h

Answer (score 1):

After one week, a workaround that works but it seems "dirty".

In fact, after go back and forward, the function `window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady']` doesn't execute anymore.

So, I put a boolean in this method, reset to `false` if it's executed. Then, a function check to need to reload after a timeout 3s by considering this value

```
 //this.needToReload = true in constructor

 ngAfterViewInit(){
    let n = 3;
    var intervalId= setInterval(() => {
            n--;
            this.tick = n*10;
            if (n === 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                if(this.needToReload)
                {
                  location.reload();
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
  } 

ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
    window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = (e) => {
        this.YT = window['YT'];
        this.needToReload = false;

        this.player = new window['YT'].Player('player', {
          videoId: '1cH2cerUpMQ'
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can destroy and reinit if youtube api has been already;

```
public player: any;
public YT: any;

init() {
  if (window['YT']) {
    window['YT'] = null;

    if(this.player){
     this.player.destroy();
    }
  this.init();
  }

  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = () => this.startVideo();
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.init();
}

startVideo() {
  this.player = new window['YT'].Player('player-youtube', {
  videoId: this.linkVideo,
  playerVars: {
    autoplay: 0,
    modestbranding: 1,
    controls: 0,
    disablekb: 1,
    rel: 0,
    showinfo: 0,
    fs: 0,
    playsinline: 1,
    loop: 0,
    origin: window.location.host,
    host: 'https://www.youtube.com'
  },
  events: {
    'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange.bind(this),
    'onReady': this.onPlayerReady.bind(this),
  }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = null;
  if (this.player) {
    this.player.destroy();
  }
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqdehh?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts)**